# How can I import MP3 tracks/folders into Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, windows-media-player, libraries, import

How can I import MP3 tracks/folders into Windows Media Player so that they appear in anything other than the '*Other*' folder?

Answer (score 4):

1. If you’re in Windows Media Player's **Now Playing** mode, click the **Switch to Library** button ([image: 1]) in the upper-right corner of the player
2. In the Player Library, click **Organize**
3. Click **Manage libraries** and then select **Music** to open the **Music Library Locations** dialog box

   [image: 2]
4. Click **Add**
5. Find the folder in the list, click **Include folder**, and then click **OK**